# Cisco Jabber 10.5 install via GPO

Tags: cisco

Cisco Jabber 10.5 install via GPO

I am trying to setup a GPO to install the latest version of Cisco Jabber. When I create the entry under Software Installation the properties for the product information state the language is Arabic. Has anyone done this and ran into this problem. I am using the .msi straight from the Cisco site unmodified. Tried all three versions of Jabber for 10.5 and they all produce the same results.

Comment: Did you verify that you downloaded the proper MSI for an English installation? (Assuming that English is what you are looking for.)

Comment: Yes I did. I got the proper MSI for English installation.